# ios core data NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am keep getting this error for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.
not sure what to do with it, since it happen sporadically.

I do create the records synchronized, but still ..

any ideas why could this be?

```
- (Activity *)createActivityWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    @synchronized([DBController sharedManaged])
    {
        Activity *act = [Activity activityWithDictionary:dict inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [self saveContext];
        return act;
    }
}


Date/Time:       2012-09-18 22:55:53.686 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x3724188f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x34f46259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                 0x37244a9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                 0x37243915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                 0x3719e650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   CoreData                       0x36a78f4d -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 2401
6   Foundation                     0x37aa64ff __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 19
7   CoreFoundation                 0x3720d547 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 71
8   CoreFoundation                 0x37199097 _CFXNotificationPost + 1407
9   Foundation                     0x37a1a3eb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
10  CoreData                       0x36a00839 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 77
11  CoreData                       0x36a0031d -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 305
12  CoreData                       0x36a09d01 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1245
13  CoreData                       0x369fd145 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 201
14  PalFinds                       0x000a57cb -[DBController saveContext] (DBController.m:75)
15  PalFinds                       0x000a8dff -[DBController createActivityWithDictionaries:] (DBController.m:852)
16  PalFinds                       0x00086649 -[PFMe finishRequest:andRestConnection:] (PFMe.m:1986)
17  PalFinds                       0x0002e17d -[RestConnection connectionDidFinishLoading:] (RestConnection.m:326)
18  Foundation                     0x37addc29 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 17
19  Foundation                     0x37a356d9 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 29
20  Foundation                     0x37a356a3 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 199
21  Foundation                     0x37a355c5 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 61
22  CFNetwork                      0x36ed97f5 URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading(URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 193
23  CFNetwork                      0x36ece4a5 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 425
24  CFNetwork                      0x36ece599 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 669
25  CFNetwork                      0x36ece599 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 669
26  CFNetwork                      0x36ece1a3 URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 107
27  CFNetwork                      0x36ece0d9 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 157
28  CoreFoundation                 0x37215ad3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
29  CoreFoundation                 0x3721529f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
30  CoreFoundation                 0x37214045 __CFRunLoopRun + 653
31  CoreFoundation                 0x371974a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
32  CoreFoundation                 0x3719736d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
33  GraphicsServices               0x33956439 GSEventRunModal + 137
34  UIKit                          0x30f43cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
35  PalFinds                       0x000038bf main (main.mm:14)
36  PalFinds                       0x00003878 start + 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's trying to call the delegate back and the delegate isn't implementing a method it's supposed to.

I'm thinking either `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` or `controllerDidChangeContent:`

Did you implement those methods in your `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this might seem far fetched BUT I had a very similar problem and I had all those methods implemented and then I realized I had my release commented out for the fetchedREsultsController...once I put that back in no more sigbart and works like a charm.

All I'm saying is that sometimes the error isn't always the obvious.

We would need to see a bit more code to figure it out.  Thanks.